# Как из flask отправлять данные в discord?

Tags: python

Стоит задача из `flask` брать 2 переменные и передавать их в `Discord`. Набросал небольшой код, но непонятно как их синхронизовать

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template

import discord
users = []
chatid = ""

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready(self):
    print('Logged on as', self.user)
    guilds = self.guilds        
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('form.html')

@app.route('/submit', methods=['POST'])
def submit():
    id = format(request.form['id'])
    token = format(request.form['token'])
    client.run('token')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: у Discord вроде как API есть? И если память мне не изменяет, flask это сервер, который получает и отправляет данные

Comment: Вот я хочу принять данные из фласка  - id и токен и подключиться с их помощью в discord

Comment: как работает фласк знаете? Заходите по ссылке /URL далее фласк выполняет код который находит под  @app.route('/URL', methods=['GET, POST']).. под синхронизацией, что вы имеете ввиду?